# Do options have CUSIP numbers?

Tags: united-states, options, cusip

If so, then where to find them?

Comment: Why do you want/need it? Option symbols are unique and follow a simple format: Ticker / Maturity Date (YYMMDD) / C|P / Strike. If a CUSIP is included, it's usually the CUSIP of the underlying.

Comment: another to look for ISIN see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number

Answer (score 2):

"Options and futures contracts do not receive CUSIPs, but nearly every other type of security does.

see: https://investinganswers.com/dictionary/c/cusip